# Selection in SwiftUI NavigationView lost if List order changes

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

This is the test data model:

```
class Item: Identifiable {
  let name: String

  init( n: Int) {
    self.name = "\(n)"
  }
}

class Storage: ObservableObject {
  @Published var items = [Item( n: 1), Item( n: 2)]

  func reverse() {
    items = self.items.reversed()
  }
}
```

This is my content view, with a `NavigationLink` and a detail view with a button that reverses the item order:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject
  var storage = Storage()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach( storage.items) { item in
          NavigationLink( destination: Button( action: {
            self.storage.reverse()
          }) {
            Text("Reverse")
          }) {
            Text( item.name).padding()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now if I tap on `Reverse` the `NavigationView` or `List` seems to lose its selection, pops the view, and pushes it again:

[image: NavigationView losing selection]

Is this expected behaviour or a bug in SwiftUI? Is there a workaround? I would expect that the detail view simply stays as it is, without reloading.

Comment: You are changing a Published Value in Observed Object. Your view will reloads, which cause the above behaviour.

Comment: The effect I'm trying to achieve is the same as e.g. the Notes app on macOS: The master view is a list that is ordered by last modified date. Then, when I click an older note and change it, the selected note moves to the top of the list. Do you think that's not possible to achieve with SwiftUI?

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify an explicit `id` for your `ForEach` loop.

If you use a static `ForEach` (without the `id` parameter) your view is rebuilt because the data (`storage.items`) is changed.

Try the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var storage = Storage()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(storage.items, id:\.name) { item in // <- add `id` parameter
                    NavigationLink(destination: self.destinationView) {
                        Text(item.name).padding()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    var destinationView: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.storage.reverse()
        }) {
            Text("Reverse")
        }
    }
}
```

This method, however, only works if the original position of selected item is maintained.

In this example performing the `update()` from the detail screen for item 1 will *not* pop the NavigationLink.

```
class Storage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Item(n: 1), Item(n: 2)]

    func update() {
        items = [Item(n: 1), Item(n: 3)]
    }
}
```

---

Here is a workaround to make it work (use an empty `NavigationLink`):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var storage = Storage()
    @State var isLinkActive = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(storage.items, id:\.name) { item in
                        Button(action: {
                            self.isLinkActive = true
                        }) {
                            Text(item.name).padding()
                        }
                    }
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: self.destinationView, isActive: $isLinkActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var destinationView: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.storage.reverse()
        }) {
            Text("Reverse")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me in Xcode 11.5, iOS 13. Did you extract the `destinationView` as well?

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted, Xcode 11.5, iOS 13 (newest). DetailView still moves around.

Comment: pawello2222, just to confirm, with your implementation: You tap a list item, and then tap "Reverse" and the detail view stays on top, without moving? And then, when tapping the back button, the list items are reversed?

Comment: @lassej Actually it worked for me until I pasted my code into the new project (I guess something was bugged). I updated my answer to include a workaround. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for your help with this. Your workaround solves the issue with the unstable detail view, but now the List view doesn't show which item is selected. On iPhone this is probably not that big of a problem, but on iPad or on a Mac I want the user be able to see which list item is currently selected if the view is shown in a split view.

Comment: Since the pushed view controller is no longer visible, selection is cleared on iPhones. At least, in UIKit. Try the work around on the iPad simulator, as selection behavior is different between iPhone and iPad UI idioms.